# Angular 5 : Dynamic Event Binding

Tags: angular, angular5

How to add dynamic event listener to dynamic element i.e. after its rendering is done using service response? I need to add dynamic event listener to particular element using some selector like element id.

Use Case : Suppose I have two elements both rendering using *ngFor over JSON from service response say:

First Elem 

 Second Elem

Now, first element JSON contains few instructions using which I need to make a dynamic function and I need to bind this newly created function to my second div. I need to do this using Angular 5 and not vanilla script

Let me explain in three simple step, what I need to do :

1) Make Dynamic function using json ( may be multiple function needs to be create for different different elements )
2) Finding my element which needs to bind ( optional )
3) Add dynamic function to corresponding elements using some event listener

Comment: can you please explain in detail?

Comment: @bhaumikshah, explained in detial

Comment: have you tried (change) function in your first div?  i mean when change occur you can fire a function for next div

Comment: How will (change) function on first div help in this case, as I need to call my dynamic function when user interacts with second div

Comment: when he interacts with your any div you can use the common function by setting some event listeners in your code so if any change occurs in your current data then you can perform dynamic action as you want

Comment: That could not be done here as there may be hundred's of such coupling div, and holding dynamic functionality of those div using common function will not be fine I guess

Comment: can you share your code on plunker or here?

Comment: Let me explain in three simple step, what I need to do :

1) Make Dynamic function using json ( may be multiple function needs to be create for different different elements )
2) Finding my element which needs to bind ( optional )
3) Add dynamic function to corresponding elements using some event listener

Answer (score 0):

We can use event binding to capture a variety of user-initiated events to initiate logic in our component class.

```
<!-- From: -->
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="{{ btnText }}">

<!-- To: -->
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="{{ btnText }}" (click)="addItem()">
```

Comment: it will helpful to AJ4 also

Comment: @chandrakant please go through question for in depth detail

Comment: @RajanDesai please go through question for in depth detail